# sum up all cells between dates that is a text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables. In first table I have project name and the cost for each project.  The project names always start with data (yyyymmdd) for instance 20171201_Project1, 20171202_Project_2 etc. In second table I have dates and Summary of language 1

What I would like to do is to sum up all projects in Sheet2 between 2 dates so if I have done 7 projects between 20171201 and 20171211 I would like to have a formula that will sum them up.

I am currently using this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!A:A,">20171201*",Sheet1!A:A,"<20171211*")
```

However, I always have to put the dates manually. What I want to do instead is to use dates from column A in Sheet2 to indicate the range of dates. You can download the  Excel file from [here](https://ufile.io/c0iix). I pout there new formula that doesn't work as well.

I have tried to use this formula but it doesn't show me correct value.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!A:A,">=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2))*",Sheet1!A:A,"<=DATE(LEFT(A3,4),MID(A3,5,2),RIGHT(A3,2))*")
```

Regards,

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, `SUMPRODUCT` may be a better fit.

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(projCosts[Project Name],8)>=TEXT(A2,"yyyymmdd"))*(LEFT(projCosts[Project Name],8)<TEXT(A3,"yyyymmdd"))*projCosts[Cost])
```

Where the dates of interest are in A2 and A3 (in this example).  Note that, depending on the precise date range you want, you may need to change the equality operators (`<`,`>=`) to include/exclude the equal sign.

Comment: thank you very much, however I am getting error on projCosts[Project Name]. I thought that this indicates to column A in Sheet1 (I have all project names here) and I've tried to put there Sheet1!A:A but it doesn't work. Can you advice?

Comment: @Adrian I made the table on shee1 a **TABLE**, renamed it `projCosts`,  and the references I used are structured references.  If you want to use hard-coded references instead, you will need to exclude Row 1 from the range since `B1` is not a numeric value.  Eg: something like `sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000000` and the same for the column B reference.  The structured references should execute more quickly, since you are not looking at the entire column, but it may not make a great deal of difference.